# sorting a php array by value, ordered smallest to largest

Tags: php

I've ready read various questions on here about sorting arrays by values in PHP but they don't seem to sort the very simple array I have.

```
Array
(
    [area1] => 4.8
    [area2] => 6.1
    [area3] => 3.6
    [area4] => 5.1
)
```

I'm trying to return an array ordered by values... so in the above example, area3, area1, area4, area2

I've tried asort, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? I'm sure it must be simple and I'm just missing something. 
Thanks.

Comment: __Post the code__ that you've tried, please.

Comment: `asort` works fine (https://ideone.com/ecUVAs)

Comment: Can also be done using uasort

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asort()` - This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.

```
$arr = array (
    'area1' => 4.8,
    'area2' => 6.1,
    'area3' => 3.6,
    'area4' => 5.1
);

asort( $arr );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [area3] => 3.6
    [area1] => 4.8
    [area4] => 5.1
    [area2] => 6.1
)
```

Doc: [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should be your solution

```
$a = ["area1" => 4.8,
    "area2" => 6.1,
    "area3" => 3.6,
    "area4" => 5.1];

asort($a);

var_dump($a);
```

> array(4) { ["area3"]=> float(3.6) ["area1"]=> float(4.8) ["area4"]=>
>   float(5.1) ["area2"]=> float(6.1) }

Comment: Both of the above are absolutely working. Very strange, I'd tried asort already.... obviously typed something wrong.

Comment: Did you assign the result of `asort($a)` back into `$a` perhaps?

Comment: @Qirel take a look [at asort manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php), the function accepts a variable by reference (&$a in this case)

Comment: My question was if OP had `$a = asort($a);`, and thus making `$a` a  boolean. ;-) I'm well aware the `asort()` is by reference, which is why I asked.

Comment: @Qirel sorry, i didn't get that the question was not for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<?php

$areas = array(
    "area1" => 4.8,
    "area2" => 6.1,
    "area3" => 3.6,
    "area4" => 5.1
);

asort($areas);
print_r($areas);

?>
```

> Array ( [area3] => 3.6 [area1] => 4.8 [area4] => 5.1 [area2] => 6.1 )